# MobX actions, computed и observable в отдельных файлах - это возможно?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

Есть ли возможность вынести `@action`, `@computed` и `@observable` сущности, из mobx store, в отдельные файлы, без <s>sms и регистрации</s> костылей?

Comment: да, это возможно

Comment: подскажи как это сделать, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, что делают декораторы, вы можете сделать вручную. По сути, они просто оборачивают вашу функцию (или значения) в собственные функции `mobx` и регистрируют прокси-доступ к ним.

Объявите все, что вы хотите разделить, в отдельных файлах. Импортируйте в любые файлы, и оборачивайте на месте.

Или сразу возвращайте обернутыми.

Не:

```
class Test {
    @observable value
}
```

А

```
class Test {
    constructor() {
        this.value;
        decorate(this, { value: observable.ref })
    }
}
```

Или если говорить про `actions`

```
// actions.js
export function increment() {
    this.counter++;
}

// Test.js
import { increment } from './actions'; 

...
constructor() {
    this.increment = action(increment.bind(this));
}
```